# Unable to mock error response in Angular component?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Hi I am writing unit test case i am using Jasmine for my Angular 5 component. On page load I am calling loadscopesdata method to populate grid in my html code. Below is my unit test case.

```
 it('Ng on init', () => {
        component.ngOnInit();
 });
```

Below is my actual component code.

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.loadScopesData();
 }
```

Below is my loadscopedata function.

```
loadScopesData() {
        this.scopeService.getScopesByTenantId(this._searchText, this._onlyActive).subscribe(results => this.onScopesDataLoadSuccessful(results), error => this.onScopesDataLoadFailed(error));
    }
```

Below is my onScopesDataLoadFailed function.

```
onScopesDataLoadFailed(error: any) {
    if (typeof error.error.title != 'undefined') {
        this.alertService.stopLoadingMessage();
        this.alertService.showMessage(error.error.title, error.error.status, MessageSeverity.error);
        this.rows = [];
        this.loadingIndicator = false;
    }
}
```

I am able to inject my mock services and get some dummy data everything works as expected but I am getting below error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at ScopeEditorComponent.onScopesDataLoadFailed (http://localhost:9876/base/boot-tests.ts?195796ce0b6971c676ffa17a1f170941fa665d9e:135378:32)
```

Below is my updated code..

```
it('Ng on init', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    it('should error', () => {
        spyOn(component['ScopeEndpoint'], 'getScopesByTenantId').and.callFake(() => Observable.throw({
            error: {
                title: 'Mocked title',
                status: 404 // Mocked status
            }
        }));
    });
});
```

Can someone help me how to handle onScopesDataLoadFailed method and get rid of this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```js
it('should error', () => {
  spyOn(component['scopeService'], 'getScopesByTenantId').and.callFake(() => Observable.throw({ error: {
    title: 'Mocked title',
    status: 404 // Mocked status
  }}));
});
```

This will mock the error returned by your service.

#### EDIT

```js
it('Ng on init', () => {
  spyOn(component['ScopeEndpoint'], 'getScopesByTenantId').and.callFake(() => Observable.throw({ error: {
    title: 'Mocked title',
    status: 404 // Mocked status
  }}));
  component.ngOnInit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added above line of code and same error still facing.

Comment: Did you undertsand that you had to put this in your current test and not just copy paste it, then wish for the best ?

Comment: yes i have added as you said. I just added above my code snippet also. still same error i am facing

Comment: But my error object is error.error.title in component! here it is error.title. Is this is the mistek?

Comment: it is `error.error.title` because you named your variable error and it contains an error object.